# Сохранение изменений MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Как сохранить результат запроса в таблицу?

```
SELECT row_number() OVER w as one, two, three, four FROM mytable WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY one, two, three, four)
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: В уже существующую таблицу? или создать новую?

Comment: @Akina Уже существующую. После обновления страницы, изменения пропадают.

Comment: Тогда `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Akina INSERT INTO mytable  row_number() OVER w as one, two, three, four FROM .... SELECT верно?

Comment: Нет. INSERT INTO (список полей) SELECT (весь твой запрос). Список полей должен иметь тот же порядок, что и в SELECT.

Comment: @Akina Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пжалста... пользуйтесь.

Comment: @Akina Почему-то получаю ошибку INSERT INTO mytable(row_number() OVER w as one, two, three, four FROM mytable WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY one, two, three, four ))

Comment: Ну наверное, потому, что интерпретировать слова "список полей" как "набор выражений" - не очень правильная идея, да и слово SELECT у Вас куда-то потерялось. Ещё раз - текст запроса НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ НИ НА БАЙТ ! Только добавляется В НАЧАЛО "шапка" INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina Вы можете привести готовую строку запроса?

Comment: `INSERT INTO newtable ( one, two, three, four ) SELECT row_number() OVER w as one, two, three, four FROM mytable WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY one, two, three, four)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если имеется готовый и дающий правильный результат запрос на выборку

```
SELECT (что-то)
FROM (откуда-то)
```

и существует задача сохранить результат такого запроса в некую уже имеющуюся таблицу, достаточно преобразовать его в запрос на добавление данных, добавив в начало блок

```
INSERT INTO имеющаяся_таблица (список полей)
SELECT (что-то)
FROM (откуда-то)
```

Какие следует соблюсти мелочи?

1. Список полей в имеющемся SELECT и в добавляемом INSERT должны точно совпадать по порядку (нельзя менять порядок, даже если имена "накрест" совпадают - имена полей при добавлении игнорируются, работает только номер поля в записи). Тем более - совпадать по количеству. Если в запросе полей нехватает - добавьте в список вывода литералов до требуемого. Это проще, чем надеяться на DEFAULT-значения (кроме автоинкремента, конечно, если он не приходит из запроса), и более контролируемо.
2. Тип поля, в которое помещается значение в части INSERT, должен иметь возможность принять тип, который имеет соответствующее поле в SELECT. Либо оно должно туда поместиться после неявного преобразования (например, сервер легко преобразует дату в текст). Также надо следить по длине значения (если итоговый текст длинноват - сервер его обрежет, правда, выдаст предупреждение), и не забывать о точности. Помните и о том, что timestamp - он с зоной времени. Ну и так далее. Если прямого соответствия нет, настоятельно рекомендую не надеяться на неявное преобразование от сервера, а подкорректировать список вывода в SELECT. Например, если нужно поместить строковое значение поля `num` в поле числового типа, то лучше заменить `SELECT num, ...` на `SELECT num+0, ...` (или, скажем, `SELECT CAST(num AS DECIMAL(16, 6)), ...` - по потребности).
3. Отдельно для тех полей-приёмников, для которых в поле-источнике может оказаться NULL, проверьте, определено ли это поле как NULLable. Если нет - либо измените свойства поля в таблице, либо замените NULL на иное значение функцией COALESCE либо IFNULL.
4. Отдельная песня - кодировки текста. Ну тут можно только посоветовать быть максимально внимательным. И, как в пункте 2, при малейшем подозрении на косяк - явно использовать функцию CONVERT.

Ну и помните, что при наличии в таблице-приёмнике автоинкремента его надо переинициализировать на новое значение, в соответствии с уже имеющимся максимальным значением. Простым ALTER TABLE. Иначе следующая вставка в таблицу может закончиться крахом.